# What is the difference between a JSON object and a JSON document?

Tags: javascript, json, console

I'm working with some data in React/Flux/Prismic. When I get it back from the API it comes through as what looks like a json object, but the console says its a "Document". Then when I get the data from my Flux store, it apparently goes through a change because the console now logs it as an "Object". The two look identical. What is the difference? See a screencap below.
[image]

I'm trying to run a prismic specific function on the returned object, but I think it must be looking for the "Document object" format because when I do it in the component and it returns as a "Document object" the function works, but it won't work on the "Object object".

Comment: I don’t know what code you used to get that `Document` object you logged, but a [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/document) and an object are two different objects created by two different functions: [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) and [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). They are completely different, but it would help to understand what code generated the `document` and what the intention behind that was.

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON document is stretching it. JSON is a string (a stringified representation of a JS object).

Comment: http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json to add to Andy's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at has nothing to do with JSON. This is simply how Chrome displays objects in the console.

The leading name (`Document`, `Object`) indicates the *type* of the object. Chrome will determine this type based on certain heuristics (which I don't know).

Maybe the objects have different prototypes, and that's why it shows a different type name.